# How to properly extract li elements from ul with beautiful soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have an html which looks like this:

```
<div class="content-container">
<h2>Description</h2>
<pre>Manage the wine production and review the production pipeline and volumes.</pre>
<h2>Alternative label</h2>
<ul>
<li><p>managing production of wine</p></li>
<li><p>supervising wine production</p></li>
<li><p>wine production managing</p></li>
<li><p>supervising production of wine</p></li>
<li><p>supervise wine production</p></li>
<li><p>wine production supervising</p></li>
<li><p>managing wine production</p></li>
</ul>
<h2>Skill type</h2>
<ul>
```

What I wanna do is collect all li elements that exist in the `<h2>Alternative label</h2>`. This is the code snippet I have so far:

```
somehtmlContent =BeautifulSoup(somehtml.content,"lxml")
for item in somehtmlContent.find_all("div", {"class": "content-container"}):
         try: 
            altlabel =  item.find(text="Alternative label")
            h2tag = altlabel.parent
            ultag = h2tag.findNext('ul')
            litags = []
            for litag in ultag:
                litags.append(litag.findNext('p').text)
            for tag in litags:
                print(tag)
         except:
            pass
```

Despite that when I print the content of the `litags` list I see all enties printed twice, as shown below:

```
managing production of wine
managing production of wine
supervising wine production
supervising wine production
wine production managing
wine production managing
supervising production of wine
supervising production of wine
supervise wine production
supervise wine production
wine production supervising
wine production supervising
managing wine production
managing wine production
```

Can someone help me understand why this happens? I appreciate any help you can provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is small bug in this line `for litag in ultag`. Instead use `for litag in ultag.find_all('li')`.
- Your code is giving some empty line when using `for litag in ultag`. And for each empty line next `<p>` tag is getting appended. That's the reason there are duplicates in code.
- This following code will work as intended

```
somehtmlContent =bsp(s,"html")
litags = []
for item in somehtmlContent.find_all("div", {"class": "content-container"}):
        print('-'*100) 
        try: 
            altlabel =  item.find(text="Alternative label")
            h2tag = altlabel.parent
            ultag = h2tag.findNext('ul')
            for litag in ultag.find_all('li'):
                litags.append(litag.findNext('p').text)
            for tag in litags:
                print(tag)
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current code with HTML snippet in your question doesn't print anything - ends in exception handler. The problem is here:

```
        for litag in ultag:
            litags.append(litag.findNext('p').text)
```

You are iterating effectively over `ultag.contents`, which holds all the tags and `NavigableStrings`. To fix this, iterate only over `<p>` tags:

```
data = '''<div class="content-container">
<h2>Description</h2>
<pre>Manage the wine production and review the production pipeline and volumes.</pre>
<h2>Alternative label</h2>
<ul>
<li><p>managing production of wine</p></li>
<li><p>supervising wine production</p></li>
<li><p>wine production managing</p></li>
<li><p>supervising production of wine</p></li>
<li><p>supervise wine production</p></li>
<li><p>wine production supervising</p></li>
<li><p>managing wine production</p></li>
</ul>
<h2>Skill type</h2>
<ul>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

somehtmlContent =BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")

for item in somehtmlContent.find_all("div", {"class": "content-container"}):
    try:
        altlabel =  item.find(text="Alternative label")
        h2tag = altlabel.parent
        ultag = h2tag.findNext('ul')
        litags = []
        for p in ultag.find_all('p'):
            litags.append(p.text)
        for tag in litags:
            print(tag)
    except:
        pass
```

Prints:

```
managing production of wine
supervising wine production
wine production managing
supervising production of wine
supervise wine production
wine production supervising
managing wine production
```

EDIT: Shorter method to get your content would be like this `soup.select('h2:contains("Alternative label") + ul p')` - This select `<h2>` that contains "Alternative label", first sibling that is `<ul>` and all `<p>` that are inside it:

```
for p in soup.select('h2:contains("Alternative label") + ul p'):
    print(p.text)
```